# Can App notifications in the notification bar be shown on lock screen (Android 5.1.1)?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, notification-bar, notification-icons

Ever since I updated my Galaxy S5 Active to 5.1.1, it has changed so that the small icons in the notifications bar are invisible on the lock screen. (But do still appear once on the home screen.) I've always found this very convenient to see what's happening on my phone. Is this still possible in 5.1.1?

Comment: Can you post screenshots showing comparison?

Comment: There is one other thing I want to be sure of. Do notifications appear on your lock screen or not? If not, then check your lock screen settings. You may have chosen to hide them. Sometimes, the option to hide only appears when you reset or change the lock-screen type (PIN/password/pattern etc.).

Comment: I don't have any screenshots for the before for it. 
 
I do not show notifications on then lock screen. The settings in the Lock Screen section only allow editing of the lock screen Notification, not the icons. I did edit the screen type and notification settings to check them. Neither made the change I was looking for.